# How to load jquery provided by django into your template

Tags: django, django-templates

How do I load jquery provided Django admin instead of downloading it again.

```
{% load admin/static %}

<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
```

instead of:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I believe django admin panel not using jquey. You have to download jquery and save in static folder

Comment: But is stated in their docs. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#jquery

Comment: Oh i don't know, I just inspect and verify the source codes, and tried using wappalyzer. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today in Django 3.2 the solution would be:

```
<script src="{% static "admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js" %}"></script>
```

source
https://gist.github.com/magopian/4078269